# How to create an animation when you open the application

Tags: android, flash, animation

I want to open a little animation when i open my application but i don't known what you do

And it must be à image gif? Or flash animation?

Answer (score 2):

you can use [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidAnimation/article.html) it's very comprehensive for your needs.

Keep in mind that in order to target old android api, use NineOldAndroids lib by Jake Wharton in order to get compatibility

Answer (score 0):

simplest way is to play video because it is built in feature in android. flash is not a good choice because user should install adobe air first.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the standard Android View animations ?

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html